# C# delegates and lambdas... not pointing to the expected method

Tags: c#

I'm reading the blog about Y combinators and there's a mention of a snippet of code posted below:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2007/02/02/anonymous-recursion-in-c.aspx

```
Func<int, int> fib = null;
fib = n => n > 1 ? fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2) : n;
Func<int, int> fibCopy = fib;
Console.WriteLine(fib(6));                        // displays 8
Console.WriteLine(fibCopy(6));                    // displays 8
fib = n => n * 2;
Console.WriteLine(fib(6));                        // displays 12
Console.WriteLine(fibCopy(6));                    // displays 18
```

> Huh!?  Notice how the result of calling fib changes and that the
>   result of calling fibCopy differs even from the result of calling fib!
>   (See if you can figure out why)

The poster mentions that this result will occur however, he doesn't mention why and I can't to see to figure it out either. The way I see it is...

```
fib -> Points to fib sequence lambda
fibCopy -> Points to fib sequence lambda
lambda -> n * 2
fib -> points to new lambda
fibCopy -> points to fib which is pointing to new lambda....
```

but obviously that's not what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your explanation is correct.

> fibCopy -> points to fib which is pointing to new lambda....

The final `fibCopy` is still the original definition:

```
n => n > 1 ? fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2) : n;
```

However, `fib` is no longer recursive, and invoking `fibCopy(6)` is actually running:

```
n => n > 1 ? (n - 1) * 2 + (n - 2) * 2 : n
```

Comment: Ahhh!! You're absolutely right. It's so simple too. Thanks! Accepting when I can.